# AngularJS $watch root scope variable for changes

Tags: angularjs

I have the following $rootScope variable which I use to save the current logged in user privilege level, then I access this variable from other controllers. Is there a way I can watch the rootScope variable for changes in order to update controllers specific variables with any changes to the root scope variable? Below is the code I am using so far, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

In app.js under .run:

```
 $rootScope.uPLevel = 0;
```

.controller

```
   $scope.$watch($rootScope.uPLevel, function() {
            $scope.userPLevel = $rootScope.uPLevel;
   }, true);
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The first parameter to `$watch` should either be a string or a function ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)).  Right now you're passing it the value of `$rootScope.uPLevel` on controller initialization.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $rootScope.uPLevel;
}, function() {
  $scope.userPLevel = $rootScope.uPLevel;
}, true);
```

Two sidenotes:

- It may be prudent to store this value in a service instead of `$rootScope`.
- If `uPLevel` is only an integer (as your example suggests) then you don't need to pass `true` as the third parameter - that's only for arrays and objects.  If you do want to watch a collection, then I suggest using `$watchCollection` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, reason I am using it in rootScope as I need a way to have it accessible from all services / controllers application wide. Do you believe having this variable inside a service is much better? if yes can you please explain why?

Comment: @MChan It's generally a bad idea to clutter up `$rootScope` for the same reasons one doesn't attach lots of variables to `window`.  Something to think about.  Don't forget to upvote!

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 is right that you should resist putting things on $rootScope, in this case I would suggest that you broadcast an event from $rootScope which all controllers/services could listen to in order to handle the change logic.

Comment: or you could use a single object and store all data inside it. this way you don't clutter the $rootScope

Comment: Plus one more vote because if you have a dynamic value to watch that is not isolated well in a specific scope, even if it's on the $window, this is a good way to go.

Answer (score 29):

I recommend watching $rootScope variables like that:

```
$scope.$watch('$root.uPLevel', function() {
    $scope.userPLevel = $rootScope.uPLevel;
});
```

This way, When current directive/controller is destroyed. It clears the watch as well. In $rootScope.$watch case, the watch stays forever.

Comment: Great idea. Perfect if you're looking for performance optimization