# What is the equivalent to $rootScope, $scope and $watch in Ionic 2 + Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I’m looking for the equivalents of Angular’s `$rootScope`, `$scope` and `$watch` in Ionic 2 using TypeScript.

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai $rootScope, $scope and $watch are variables. in previous version of IONIC i used [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738482/angularjs-watch-root-scope-variable-for-changes). But it may different in the Typescript. so wanting to know equivalent.  Thanks...

Comment: So you are migrating from Angular?

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai: Yes,  some of issues are overcome in IONIC 2 with this reason want to use Ionic 2.

Comment: I have edited your question accordingly. However, it would be better if you could provide some additional details, like pieces of code you already wrote and not working as intended, or some signs of research you have done in the topic.

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai: i just got [This Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985009/angular-2-what-is-equivalent-to-root-scope/35985880#35985880) during research work.  but it is not well enough.

Comment: By the way thanks @GergelyPolonkai

Comment: For equivalent to $rootScope look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266176/4356754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the exact equivalent but I have replaced it with the following:

$rootScope: Providers that handle the storage

```
export class AppGames {
    get GAME_NAMES(): any {
        return 'pizza/hut';
    }
```

$scope: `this`

```
export class BuyTopUpModalPage {
    dataList: any = [];
    constructor() {
      this.dataList = ['we', 'won']
    }
```

$watch: Observable

Comment: It is the accepted answer as it goes by the standards of Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

For equivalent to $rootScope, you can use base class for all components and place all shared vars and methods

look at this answer for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266176/4356754